# escape '+' character in azure connection string using POSTMAN

Tags: string, azure, connection

I have created a back end Web API.It gets the azure connection string and hub name as parameter.The azure connection string contains '+' sign but when it is passed as parameter the'+' sign disappears. I have to retain the + sign and not render it.How can I do so through POSTMAN.Please suggest.

Comment: seems to be an open issue with POSTMAN https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2517 . maybe you can try to encode the url and then send it.

Comment: I tried sending it by replacing '+' with %2b and it is working using POSTMAN now.

Comment: glad that it worked for you.